# Google App Engine not saving a list of objects in a class

Tags: java, google-app-engine, datanucleus

I am using DataNeucleus JDO implementation which works fine on my test server but does not work well when deployed.I am new to GAE and I know I that not all DataNeucleus features are supported. Not sure how to make this work.

I have a class say :

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class MyInfoClass {


  @PrimaryKey
  @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
  Key key;

  @Persistent(mappedBy = "myInfoClass")
  private List <BuddyData> buddyList;

  ...
}
```

And the BuddyData

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class BuddyData {

...
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    Key key;

    // the one-to-many rel to MyInfoClass -> BuddyData
    @Persistent
    private MyInfoClass myInfoClass;

....

}
```

I save the data to data store as below which works in test environment but does not work when deployed to app engine.

```
        PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
        Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
        try {
            tx.begin();
            //NOTE : myInfo is the persistent MyInfoClass object retrieved from the datastore
            myInfo.getBuddyList().add(new BuddyData(email));
            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (tx.isActive()) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
            pm.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Owned relationships can be quite tricky in GAE. I remember battling with them for hours.

First of all, you have an owned relationship cycle. I doubt that is supported by GAE. So you will need to change one of the entities to use `Key` to reference the other one, instead of the direct object relationship (i.e. owned relationship).

For example:

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class BuddyData {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    Key key;

    // use Key instead of MyInfoClass
    @Persistent
    private Key myInfoClass;
}
```

Secondly, when retrieving `BuddyData` list make sure the `PersistenceManager` is still open. If you do it like this:

```
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
MyInfoClass info = pm.getObjectById(MyInfoClass.class, key);
pm.close();
info.getBuddyList();
```

Then contents of `buddyList` will be empty.

In such case you either need to move `pm.close()` after `getBuddyList()`, or set it as the default fetch group (see below), which will eagerly prefetch all contents at a potential performance cost.

```
@Persistent(mappedBy = "myInfoClass", defaultFetchGroup = "true")
private List <BuddyData> buddyList;
```

Good luck.

Comment: using Key instead of MyInfoClass in the relationship caused error when datanucleus enhanced the class. However, calling pm.makePersistent() within the transaction helped save the list successfully. I am accepting your answer anyhow for good pointers.-thanks!